# How to recognise they have added arrow buttons in SAPUI5 sap.tnt.SideNavigation? Is there any event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am using **sap.tnt.SideNavigation** to show the content but I want to do something on adding arrow icons(Once the screen size is reduced). So is there any event to inform that or any alternative to achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sap.ui.Device.resize.attachHandler(fnHandler,oControl);
```

> try this.
>
> well after bit working around i have finally found one thing it may be usefull for you check for 'ursideNavigationbar.getDomRef().firstElementChild.style.display==='none' it means arrow button is not visible and if 'Block' it means it is visible hope it works.

Comment: Actually I don't have to check whether resizing is happening or not. This sap.tnt.sidenavigation adds the up and down arrow to toolbar content if the content height is more than current screen height. So I should come to know once it's added those up and down arrows.

Comment: you can get those arrows and check if they are available or not by '_getTopArrowControl()' and '_getBottomArrowControl()'

Comment: well after bit working around i have finally found one thing it may be usefull for you check for 'ursideNavigationbar.getDomRef().firstElementChild.style.display==='none' it means arrow button is not visible and if 'Block' it means it is visible hope it works.